# VBA - how do I stop the loop caused by the filter updating?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I want to update a normal filter when a cell within the filter is calculated.

I have a list in the range A2:A10, if it displays 1 then show the row, if it's 0 then hide the row. In the range A2:A10 I have formulas which calculates if it should be 0 or 1. I only need to update the filter if the value change and I do this with this VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim RG As Range
    Set RG = Range("A2:A10")
    If Not Intersect(RG, Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    End If
End Sub
```

But whenever the macro runs, excel freezes. I believe this is because a loop is created which never stops. When the filter is updated, that will cause the macro to run again.
I only need it to update the filter when the value in the range is changed, but it updates the filter when the filter is updated, which will update the filter again. So, a loop is created which causes excel to freeze.

I also get a:

```
run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation error
```

The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False .... Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: Do you understand what BigBen suggested?

Comment: yes, but I got more help from Ricardo Diaz. see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions on your code:

- Add `EnableEvents = false` so nothing else is triggered by the changes you make with the macro (and reenable them at the end of the procedure)
- Name your variables to something meaningful e.g. `targetRange` instead of `RG`
- Use at least a basic error handling `On error Goto`
- As you have this code behind a `Worksheet` you can refer to that worksheet as `Me` instead of `ActiveSheet`

---

About the logic:

This line is redundant

```
If Not Intersect(targetRange, Me.Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then
```

You are defining the range as Range("A2:A20")

```
Set targetRange = Me.Range("A2:A10")
```

I left it so you can change it to whatever you want to check

---

**Refactored code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    ' Disable events so nothing else is triggered by the changes you make with the macro
    Application.EnableEvents = False
       
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Me.Range("A2:A10")

    ' This next line doesn't make sense, you're comparing the same ranges
    If Not Intersect(targetRange, Me.Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("$A$1:$B$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    End If
    

CleanExit:
    ' Reenable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, 
I understand the code and why it's better but I agree that the "if not intersect" line doesn't make sense, but then again, why did you leave it in the "refactored code"?
Your code works exactly as I need it to, so that's great, thank you! But I don't understand why the intersect works, is it because when the range changes it will run through the if statement again? It even works when connecting the formulas in the range to other sheets. So thank you very much!

Comment: You can delete that line along with the `End If`. I'm glad it helped

Comment: I did, and it still works. I also added another if statement to be able to turn it off. as this will be a part of a big file which might need some debugging from time to time! 
Thank you @Ricardo

Comment: You could use the cahnge event instead of the calculate in there the intersect check makes more sense

Comment: Since I removed the "intersect" I no longer have any use of the "targetRange", So i'm not sure why it works, I only need it to work when that specific range change value, but if I understand the code, I guess that it "works" whenever any cell is calculated within the sheet?

Comment: Exactly. it works whenever there's a calculation. If you need it to a specific range, please post a new question and let me know so I can take a look at it